# How do I communicate back and forth with a popped up window

Tags: javascript, dom, domdocument

In my web page I use this function to show a small pop up Window

```
function popup (url) 
{
     poppedUpWindow= window.open(url, "PopupWindow", "width=400,height=300");
     poppedUpWindow.focus();
     return false;
}
```

I need to share objects between thoos 2 windows.
I tried doing something like this but it does now work

```
poppedUpWindow.document.documentElement.addEventListener("load", foo, false);
```

Is also possible that I do something like this

```
 function popup (url) 
    {
         poppedUpWindow= window.open(url, "PopupWindow", "width=400,height=300");
         var tmp = poppedUpWindow.document;
         tmp.write('<html><head><title>popup</title>');
         ....
         tmp.close();
         poppedUpWindow.focus();
         return false;
    }
```

But this approach will make solving the problem much harder.
So how should I transfer information from the parent window to the popped up window and vice versa?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage):

Send a message like this:

```
otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin);
```

otherWindow can listen for dispatched messages by executing the following JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080")
    return;

  // ...
}
```

Keep in mind browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging
IE 8+, Firefox 3+, Chrome all versions, Opera 9.5+, Safari 4+

Comment: The postMessage is what I was missing actually. I had to figure out other problems though and I posted how I did that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved the issue for anyone else facing the same issue.
I am considering the browser to be either chrome or firefox. I did not test other browsers. The event "load" in Chrome sometimes gets fired before the whole javascript files loads.

```
function popup (url) 
{
     poppedUpWindow= window.open(url, "PopupWindow", "width=400,height=300");
     poppedUpWindow.focus();


if(is_chrome)
         {
         window.setTimeout("doSomething()",300); //this value could vary! 300ms seemed fine to me!
         }
     else
         {
            fenster.addEventListener('load', doSomething, true); //  FireFox 
         }
 return false;
}

function doSomething()
{
    poppedUpWindow.postMessage("hi","*");
var a = poppedUpWindow.document.getElementById("b");
// do anything you want..

}
```

In the other html there should be this method

```
function receiveMessage(event)
{
  if (event.origin !== stringUrlOfFirstWebPage)
    { 
       return;
    }
    event.source.postMessage("hey!",event.origin);//talking back to the first web page
}
```